# Is there a way to enter recovery mode without using home and volume keys?

Tags: rooting, samsung, recovery-mode, home-button, volume-buttons

I have a **Samsung** device and i need to use the **Android recovery mode** for some reason.As for **Samsung**, i have to use the **volume-down** and **home key** to enter **recovery mode**

But the problem is, my **home key** is broken and as a result, I can't use the normal way to enter **recovery mode**.

I can use **ADB** to do that with my **PC** but i can't do that every time when i need.

**So, is there a way to do that without using the home key?**

> Note: My phone is **not rooted** and i know that i can change the **recovery mode entering configuration** easily if i **root** my phone but i don't want to **root** my phone.

Answer (score -1):

If your device boots fully, `adb reboot recovery` should take you there. However, if your device is rooted, then you can use [Quick Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awiserk.kundalias.rootboot) in the Play Store will get the job done.

UPDATE: Due to a change in the question, the answer would be that this is not possible without root access or being able to use the buttons on the phone.

Comment: This does not answer the question, he does not ask for (pc) adb or root

Comment: @alecxs The question's parameters have changed since my answer... The answer on an unrooted device is that outside of using adb, there is no way to enter recovery on this device without use of the keys. I will update my answer.

Comment: i didn't know that, because the question has no edited state. Anyway i wouldn't say impossible, maybe there is a way with short circuiting pins via usb dongle, who knows? afaik Samsung has USB OTG support, this means it might possible to run automated adb commands from Hak5 Rubber Ducky

Comment: @alecxs True... But if the user isn't willing to root, I find it unlikely they would want to use a 3rd party piece of equipment or disassemble the device to access any contacts. I made the assumption since they did not want to root, that they wanted to do it on the device itself, in which case I stand by my answer.

Comment: @acejavelin, i didn't change my question parameters, you didn't notice that i told in my question that i know i can use pc to do it but i want to be able to do without pc.

Comment: @shiro13 Your original question did not note that root was not an option, so my original answer gave you your options. You added the part about you not having root, and not wanting to root either, after the fact. I still stand by my answer, reboot into recovery requires a privileged user account that applications cannot access directly from the device without root.

Comment: only for Download Mode, unfortunately https://www.amazon.com/Download-Samsung-Android-Smartphone-Unbrick/dp/B01HQ0DJR2

Answer (score -1):

- install Terminal Emulator
  http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm
- type from terminal

  reboot recovery

Comment: this one should work without root

Comment: That terminal app would provide shell access with unprivileged abilities. You need a privileged user, such as shell (user 2000), system (user 1000), or root itself.

Comment: at least, it works for me with explicitly rejected su permissions

Comment: @alecxs i want to inform you that the command didn't work.I did some digging and found that the command is actually 'su -c reboot recovery' but as you can see, it's a superuser command and i can't use that.

Comment: have tested on my mothers phone, it says permission denied. must be a bug in SuperSU or something messed up on my phone

Comment: @alecxs SELinux would be permissive on your phone when you tested but enforcing on your mother's. It's only SELinux which restricts apps from setting properties.