# i can't boot into recovery mode on my Nokia C2 tennen

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, nokia

When using the hardware key combination( Volume up + Power button)it doesn't go into recovery mode at all
The only option I'm able to get is fastboot (Volume down + power button)
can anyone help me??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to enter recovery mode without using home and volume keys?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213075/is-there-a-way-to-enter-recovery-mode-without-using-home-and-volume-keys)

Comment: Nope..But thanks

Comment: you can factory reset from [google](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)

Comment: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/nokia/nokia-c2-tennen/recovery-mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'adb reboot recovery' ? Works on all my devices.

Comment: when I do it gives "error no device/emulators found"

Comment: are sure about that? reboot recovery requires root access

Comment: Is your device powering on? If yes, then you need to enable the developer mode in Settings -> about phone. You can find hundreds of how-to with a little googling.
https://www.carlcare.com/global/tips-detail/how-to-enable-or-disable-developer-options-android

If not, for motorola devices, when you enter fastboot, you can press Vol+/Vol down to select the options. One of the options is the recovery mode. Then just press power button to select.
@alecxs, yes I'm sure that 'adb reboot recovery' don't require root access.

Comment: I can't get to settings, Because I'm locked out of my phone that's why I'm trying to get to the recovery mode to hard reset it...But the key combination doesn't work @DenisRosas

Comment: Could you try this? https://youtu.be/etXb1bg2NCY?t=42

Comment: Didn't work..But thanks